# Putnam 1996 A3 "paradox"

Tags: combinatorics, contest-math, pigeonhole-principle

Each of 20 students has made a choice of anywhere from 0 to 6
courses from a total of 6 courses offered. Prove or disprove: there are 5 students and 2
courses such that all 5 have chosen both courses or all 5 have chosen neither course.

The statement is false and you can look up the proof. However, I have an argument that "proves" it is true, please tell me what I'm doing wrong.

Assume that for any two courses, fewer than 5 students have chosen both courses. Let $C_1$ be the most chosen course, by $k$ students namely $S_1,\dots, S_k$. Any course other than $C_1$ could have been chosen by at most 4 of $S_1,\dots, S_k$ and at most $20-k$ of $S_{k+1},\dots, S_{20}$. Thus, $k\geq (20-k)+4$ or $k\geq12$. Now, we can easily see that there are 5 students of $S_1,\dots, S_k$ who didn't choose two of $C_2,\dots, C_5$.

Comment: Isn't $(20-k) + 4$ an upper bound on the course size?

Comment: @user51547 I assumed that $k$ is the upper bound, so everything else $\leq k$.

Comment: Imagine $k=10.$ Then any other course could have been chosen by at most $20-k+4=14$ students. But that doesn't imply $10 \geq 14$.

Comment: in "at most $20-k$ of $S_{k+1},\dots, S_{20}$. Why $20-k$? Can you expand on the reasoning there?

Comment: @AlexK $20-k$ meaning all of $S_{k+1},\dots,S_{20}$ may take a course.

Comment: @user51547 you can't set $k=10$ and arrive at a contradiction, because I assumed that the maximum is reached at some number, called it $k$, derived a condition on it, and computed its possible values. Please elaborate more if you think something is missing here

Comment: For $i\neq1$, you argued why $|C_i| \leq k$, and why $|C_i| \leq (20 - k) +4$. But why should the second bound be tighter than the first?

Comment: @user51547 I see what you're getting at, but my argument is: assume the possible case: $C_2$ is picked by $S_{k+1},\dots, S_{20}$ and $S_{1},S_{2},S_3,S_4$. So, $C_2$ was chosen by $24-k$ students and since $k$ is the maximum, the latter is greater than the former. Do you think there's a problem with this reasoning?

Comment: Agree if you can show the upper bound is achieved for some $i$, then $24-k=|C_i|\leq k$. But I think that still needs to be shown.

Comment: The problem is,  while you can assume that all of $S_{k-1}\dots S_{20}$ to get an upper bound, that's not an upper bound that you can use the way you did -- you need a tight upper bound. By construction, that's $min(k,24-k)$

Answer (score 2):

Community wiki answer so the question can be marked as answered:

As discussed in the comments, you can’t conclude that $k\geq (20-k)+4$ merely from the fact that at most $(20-k)+4$ students have chosen any other course. To conclude this, there would actually have to be a course that achieves that (very loose) bound.